# changing the startup keyboard of an app

Tags: c#, wpf

My problem is that I want my application to run as a Hebrew application. and by that I mean the when I'll type something through out the application it'll be by default in Hebrew and not in English.

Every question I saw in here was how to change the controls culture.
I tried changing the cultureinfo to he-IL when the main window loaded... but it didn't help and the application was still set to be in English.

I am probably doing something wrong, please direct to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the culture before controls are initialized. Set this in constructor before `InitializeComponent();`

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("he-IL");
```

**EDIT**
To change the keyboard input language, see this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.currentinputlanguage.aspx)

Comment: didn't help for the entire app... should I put it on every form? also to make everything clear I want the language that is near the clock in windows to be set to Hebrew.

Comment: @SagiRokach are you sure you have set the form's property `Localizable` to true? And yes, every form runs in separate thread afaik, so you have to set it for every form

Comment: I'm running a WPF application. And looking at the form properties I didn't see any Localizable property. where should I look for that property? also I don't want to change the content or texts on the controls, only to change the keyboard. thanks.